Moments of normalized multivariate Gaussians (and Wick's/Isserlis theorems)
Suppose $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$ is distributed according to the real two-dimensional Gaussian with mean-$0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I am interested in a closed form for the expectation of $\frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$.
Ideally, there exists a Wick's (Isserlis) type formula for the higher moments of the normalized Gaussian distribution. To be more clear, suppose $x$ is a centered (i.e., mean-$0$) real $n$-dimensional Gaussian with (general positive definite) covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Now suppose $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|_2}$. The distribution of $y$ is what I am calling in this post the "normalized Gaussian" distribution (perhaps a terrible choice given how loaded normal is). Could we express the expectation of $y_1y_2y_3y_4$ in terms of expectations of $y_i y_j$?
From wrestling with this problem for a day it seems even the case of diagonal $\Sigma$ is out of reach. We seem to only know the case of IID Gaussians (i.e., $\Sigma = I$). In this case the distribution of the normalized random variables is the Haar measure (i.e., uniform distribution) on the unit sphere. For Haar measure we have a Wick's formula, for example see the wonderful observations in the following post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619629/wick-theorem-for-uniform-measure-on-n-sphere

Update: Here is the solution for the quadratic moments of the 2-dimensional problem. These are obtained by directly calculating the integral. Let $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1 & \sigma_{12}\\\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2\end{bmatrix}$ and let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be its eigenvalues.  Then we have
$\mathbb{E} \frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2} =  \frac{\sigma_{12}}{(\sqrt{\lambda_1} + \sqrt{\lambda_2})^2},$
$\mathbb{E} \frac{x_1^2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2} = \frac{\sigma_{1} + \sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{(\sqrt{\lambda_1} + \sqrt{\lambda_2})^2},$
$\mathbb{E} \frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2 + x_2^2} = \frac{\sigma_{2} + \sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}{(\sqrt{\lambda_1} + \sqrt{\lambda_2})^2}
$.
Update 2:
Indeed one can find Isserlis-type formulas (at least in the two-dimensional case so far). Let $y_i = \frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}$, for $i = 1,2$. Then again by direct calculation of the integrals we have
$\mathbb{E}y_1^2y_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1y_2]^2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1^2]\mathbb{E}[y_2^2],$
$\mathbb{E}y_1^3y_2 = \mathbb{E}[y_1^2]\mathbb{E}[y_1y_2],$
$\mathbb{E}y_1 y_2^3 = \mathbb{E}[y_1y_2]\mathbb{E}[y_2^2],$
$\mathbb{E}y_1^4 = \mathbb{E}[y_1^2]^2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1^2]\mathbb{E}[y_2^2]- \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1y_2]^2,$
$\mathbb{E}y_2^4 = \mathbb{E}[y_2^2]^2 + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1^2]\mathbb{E}[y_2^2]- \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[y_1y_2]^2.$
I am hoping these formulas have been proven in full generalities for all moments and all dimensions in the literature.

Update 3:
The paper "An extension of Wick’s theorem" by Vignat and Bhatnagar answers my question partially.
To state the result we need a quick definition also borrowed from the paper. A pairing $\pi$ on the set $I_{2m} = \{1,\ldots,2m\}$ is a partition of $I_{2m}$ into $m$ disjoint pairs. Let $I_{2m}/\pi$ be the quotient by the equivalence relation induced by the pairing $\pi$. For example when $\pi = \{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ then $I_4/\pi = \{\overline{1},\overline{3}\}$ where $\overline{1}$ is simply the equivalence class of $1$, which in this case is $\{1,2\}$. For another example when $\pi = \{(1,3),(2,4)\}$ then $I_4/\pi = \{\overline{1},\overline{2}\}$.
Let $x$ be sampled from the standard $n$-dimensional real Gaussian (i.e., with mean $0$ and covariance $I$ the identity matrix). Let $\Sigma$ be any positive definite matrix. Let $y = \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} x/\|x\|_2$. Also let $\sigma_{ij}$ denote the $(i,j)$ entry of $\Sigma$. Then we have
$$\mathbb{E}[y_{i_1}y_{i_2}\cdots y_{i_{2m}}] = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{2^m \Gamma(m + \frac{n}{2})}\sum_\pi \prod_{\overline{k}\in I_{2m}/\pi} \sigma_{i_k i_{\pi(k)}},$$
and the odd moments are obviously zero.
Unfortunately, I am interested in a Wicks formula for the random vectors distributed as $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} x/\|\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} x\|_2$. But this paper only gives one for $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} x/\|x\|_2$ which has an elliptic distribution.

I link here the relevant references I found useful so far:
An extension of Wick’s theorem
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715208001405
A wonderful short expository paper by Folland titled "How to integrate a polynomial over a sphere"
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695802
A generalized Isserlis theorem for location mixtures of Gaussian random vectors
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715211002951
A general Isserlis theorem for mixed-Gaussian random variables
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715211001052
A generalized Isserlis theorem for location mixtures of Gaussian random vectors
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715211002951
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619629/wick-theorem-for-uniform-measure-on-n-sphere
And the highly delightful notes in the accepted answer of the following stackexchange post:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616234/how-to-prove-isserlis-theorem-ex-1x-2x-3x-4-ex-1x-2ex-3x-4-ex-1x-3
And if you wanted to laboriously calculate the integrals (like I did in my post but do not recommend!) the following Wikipedia article is very useful
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral
and a beautiful description of some of these integral formulas in the accepted answer of
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126227/reference-for-multidimensional-gaussian-integral
